# CSS Image border Remove

Tags: html, css

I just trying to solve the problem.

### [image]

CSS:

```
.default-img > img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('bg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

I have a white "Border" (Inner Border?) in the Image tag and i cant remove it.
The Black Border is set manually to show you the Problem and the Red Content is the included image.

How can i remove the white inner border from img tag

Comment: seems like that white border is part of your image (look at the image before a dark background to check that) - open it in an image editor and remove it by cutting it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open up a image editing software. Re-crop / re-save your source image
  being rendering from '`background: url('bg.png');`' background
  property. So, the '`bg.png`'.
- Another thing you can do if you don't want to do above. Nest another
  `<div>` around your initial `.default-img` `<div>` and set the
  heights and widths to crop out the white. Make sure to set property
  `overflow:hidden;`
- In some rarer cases a white line or (outline) can be induced around
  elements as a browser quirk. Test your element across browsers (and
  maybe even devices too) to target if it's something browser
  specific. Then target that browser and remove. *ie.* `outline { none; }`

Hope this helps, g'luck!

Comment: Indeed! it was browser specific. Thanks for the Help. I have changed the img tag with a div tag and now it works!

Comment: Sweet. glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

The `img` creates that border when you have a background but not a source.

To solve this issue move that background to a `div` :)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that that white border exists in the image itself, not in css? view the file on the black background and check.

Comment: Yes, and if it is there and you can't remove, set this image as background, set background-size a bit larger than div.
If not, play with img {border:none !important;}

Comment: Thanks, but i have checked the image. That was my first though.

Comment: @klepzers first one worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are showing two images there at 100%, both the source image and the background image. Do you need the background image? Could that cause the white line?